ArCore won't track downloaded image
I'm trying to create an image tracker using ArCore. The sample images that are loaded in the sample project track fine. However the images I download and add to the augmentedImageDb don't track. Those same images work if I add them to the project's assets folder but no images added at runtime work.
Here's the code that works (add at build time)
private Bitmap loadAugmentedImageBitmap() {
    try (InputStream is = getAssets().open("default.jpg")) {
      return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "IO exception loading augmented image bitmap.", e);
    }
    return null;
  }
//called here 
Bitmap augmentedImageBitmap = loadAugmentedImageBitmap();
    if (augmentedImageBitmap == null) {
      return false;
    }

    augmentedImageDatabase = new AugmentedImageDatabase(session);
    augmentedImageDatabase.addImage("image_name", augmentedImageBitmap);

Images downloaded at runtime that doesn't track. (db count shows they are in the db)
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
augmentedImageDatabase.addImage("image_name", image);

Note that the download and storing of images in the db happen on a background thread.
Any thoughts on why these aren't tracking even though they appear to be in the db?

This issue is not due to downloading images. It has to do with creating the database and adding to it after it has already been configured. Closing this.
